# Refine selections step-by-step until reach the desired product

Tags: web-frontend

i'm working on a project to create a product selector with multiple items selection simply refine selections step-by-step until reach the desired product.

i have no idea how to strat it from scratch,

for the refrence i found a working link

https://www.pepperl-fuchs.com/global/en/productselector.htm?view=productselection&paramlist=143-1340-121499%2C143-2960-119976%2C143-1-109981%2C&classid=143&step1=FA&step2=142&step3=143&reload=true#overview

That's what the client needs.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design your system in two ways

1. All select / checkboxes for different options without dependency on previous selection -> With that you just need to send everytime your search request with additional search params from all selected options.
2. Show next possible options based on previous one -> With that you need to send request for getting next possible options to server based on selected prev options. This should happen everytime for all possible options until last one which should return all products (lets say). This means that multiple events are required.